# Css twitter widget stays outside the element in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter, widget

I've added this twitter widged to one of the site's i manage and for some reason, in every browser but firefox it looks good but in firefox this happens
[image]

bam it jump to the side for no reason i solved this by putting overflow:hidden; to the class textwidget
but then everything is gone in the rest of the browsers?

could anyone help me find a solution for this.

All help is very much appreciated

p.s. the site can be found here
[Popdrommen](http://werun.nyheter24.se/popdrommen/)

Comment: I've tried to have a look at it - I don't know if it's only my computer, but there is so much stuff (especially videos) loaded on the site that it almost made my browser crash. After loading, my CPU was up to 90%, which made it quite impossible for me to inspect things with firebug. So, this is off-topic, but take it as an advice: Try to scale your content somehow instead of loading it all at once!

Comment: In relation to Quasdunk above; maybe post the related html+css code here? I know I had a similar issue with firefox when trying to position an absolute div inside a relative positioned div with display table-cell. It might be completely different, but without code we can't tell ;)

Comment: y i know but not I who made the site from the beginning I've just started and i have alot in my todo list :) so eventually it will be all scaled down but for now i recommend u using adblocker plus ;)

Comment: well if u visit the site use firebug or google element inspect tool and u'll get the applied styles and what not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After successfully defeating your popup window, I have come to a conclusion that something like this should help you:

```
.textwidget {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do in my opinion, is create a div, set its size, and then apply the overflow:hidden attribute to it, (remember to position it relativly)

Then inside that div put the twitter stuff.

```
<div style="width:200px; height:500px; position:relative; overflow:hidden">
    <!-- Twitter stuff here //-->
</div>
```